# Python protobuf decode base64 string

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

I am trying to get JSON data from encrypted base64 string. I have created my proto file like below

```protobuf
syntax = "proto2";

message ArtifactList {
    repeated Artifact artifacts = 1;
}

message Artifact {
    required string id = 1;
    required uint64 type_id = 2;
    required string uri = 3;
}
```

After that, I have generated python files using the proto command. I am trying to decrypt the base64 string like below.

```
import message_pb2

import base64
data = base64.b64decode("AAAAAA8KDQgTEBUgBCjln62lxS6AAAAAD2dycGMtc3RhdHVzOjANCg==")

s = str(data)
message_pb2.ArtifactList.ParseFromString(s)
```

But I am getting the below error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 7, in <module>
    message_pb2.ArtifactList.ParseFromString(s)
TypeError: descriptor 'ParseFromString' requires a 'google.protobuf.pyext._message.CMessage' object but received a 'str'
```

I am a newbie for protobuf. I couldn't find a solution to fix this issue.

Could anyone help to fix this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why did you delete the other question with my answer?

Comment: @jps I have asked a question, that was wrong. That's why I have deleted that. But your answer is correct.

Comment: Do you have any idea regarding this question?

Comment: @jps Now I am getting this error. Do you have any idea?

Comment: I am getting this error:- `google.protobuf.message.DecodeError: Wrong wire type in tag.`. Can anyone help

Comment: @Sanjiv are you using python2 or 3?

Comment: @ChenA.:- Python 3

Comment: @Sanjiv print the type before you call the function, it might be unicode. `print(type(s))`

Answer (score 4):

There are two issues.

1. ParseFromString is a method of an ArtifactList instance
2. ParseFromString takes a byte-like object, not str, as parameter

```
>>>import message_pb2
>>>import base64
>>>data = base64.b64decode("AAAAAA8KDQgTEBUgBCjln62lxS6AAAAAD2dycGMtc3RhdHVzOjANCg==")
>>>m=message_pb2.ArtifactList()
>>>m.ParseFromString(data)
>>>m.artifacts
<google.protobuf.pyext._message.RepeatedCompositeContainer object at 0x7fd09a937d68>
```

Answer (score 1):

ParseFromString is a method on an protobuf Message *instance*.

Try:

```
message = message_pb2.ArtifactList()
message.ParseFromString(s)
```

Comment: I am getting this error:- `google.protobuf.message.DecodeError: Wrong wire type in tag.` can anyone help?